# Create d3 map with geo-albers-usa-territories projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

I'm trying to create a map with d3.js using the geo-albers-usa-territories projection- found here: https://github.com/stamen/geo-albers-usa-territories

I've tried to model my code after this [Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@almccon/u-s-map-with-puerto-rico-us-virgin-islands-american-samoa-gua) that uses the projection, but things have very clearly gone awry:

[image]

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any help is welcome. Code below:

```js
let margin = { top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 10, left: 50 },
            width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        let projection = geoAlbersUsaTerritories.geoAlbersUsaTerritories()
            .scale(1200)
            .translate([520, 305]);

        const path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        const svg = d3.select("#content")
            .append("svg")
            .attr('id', 'map')
            .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

        const map = svg.append('g')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .attr('class', 'map')

        d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json").then(function (us) {

            map.selectAll('path')
                .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation))
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("class", "outline")
                .attr("stroke", "red")

            map.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("class", "mesh")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr('fill', 'none')
                .attr('stroke', 'blue')

        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Map with territories</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/geo-albers-usa-territories@0.1.0/dist/geo-albers-usa-territories.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like it was a problem w/ the json I was calling. I've got it working now:

```js
        let margin = { top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 10, left: 50 },
            width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        let projection = geoAlbersUsaTerritories.geoAlbersUsaTerritories()
            .scale(width)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2.2]);

        const path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        const svg = d3.select("#content")
            .append("svg")
            .attr('id', 'map')
            .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

        const map = svg.append('g')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .attr('class', 'map')

        d3.json("https://unpkg.com/us-atlas@3.0.0/states-10m.json").then(function (usa) {

            map.selectAll('path')
                .data(topojson.feature(usa, usa.objects.nation).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("class", "outline")
                .attr("stroke", "red")

            map.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(usa, usa.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("class", "mesh")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr('fill', 'none')
                .attr('stroke', 'blue')

        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Map with territories</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/geo-albers-usa-territories@0.1.0/dist/geo-albers-usa-territories.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```